# Throw exception if the expected header field is not in the received .csv file

Tags: csv, parsing, univocity

Is it possible to throw exception when the expected header fields are not present in csv file, while parsing it via univocity parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you processing the file into java beans? If that is the case, on your `BeanProcessor` instance, call `setStrictHeaderValidationEnabled(true)` and it will validate the input headers against the fields annotated with the `@Parsed` annotation.